# How to run a pod on each Node with nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes

I am using nodeSelector but I want to run it in a pod on each node. I'm doing as below. What is the best way?

```
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - test-1
                - test-2
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool
                operator: In
                values:
                - test-node
```

Comment: What sort of resource are you deploying? The default behavior of a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) is to run a pod on each node.

Comment: Just use daemonsets . https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your live easier by using a built-in resource suitable for that specific requirement "one pod per node". This resource is called "DaemonSet".

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
 name: my-ds
spec:
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: my-ds
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: my-ds
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: ds-run
     image: httpd
```